# Using grep/awk/sed to sort and combine 2 files

Tags: sed, awk, scripting, grep, join

I am taking a wifi log that has MAC addresses listed in it. I want to find out what MAC vendors/manufacturers for the devices that are connected to my router. I have 2 files, one with the MACs already 'grep' to show the first 3 octets for the MAC. The other file has a list of vendors and their first 3 octets they were issued. Right now the issue is that the first file has multiple duplicates which I can still match in the second file but it won't show how many it has from the first file. Below are the examples.

text.txt

```
00:10:f6
00:10:f6
03:48:03
8f:91:34
93:ab:c6
```

vendor.xml

```
03:48:03 vendor="apple"
00:10:f6 vendor="micro"
8f:91:34 vendor="dell"
93:ab:c6 vendor="sun"
23:8b:23 vendor="acer"
00:73:ad vendor="asus"
```

This is what I get when I run the following code:

```
cat text.txt vendor.xml |grep -Ff text.txt vendor.xml |sort -u |uniq -c >> final.txt
```

final.txt

```
  1 00:10:f6 vendor="micro"
  1 03:48:03 vendor="apple"
  1 8f:91:34 vendor="dell"
  1 93:ab:c6 vendor="sun"
```

The result should be instead:

```
  2 00:10:f6 vendor="micro"
  1 03:48:03 vendor="apple"
  1 8f:91:34 vendor="dell"
  1 93:ab:c6 vendor="sun"
```

Is there some flag or option I am not thinking of?

Comment: Actually - some flag you maybe overthought. remove the `-u` from `sort` and you might like the results.

Answer (score 8):

`join` combines the files (needing sorted inputs):

```
$ join <(sort text.txt) <(sort vendor.xml)
00:10:f6 vendor="micro"
00:10:f6 vendor="micro"
03:48:03 vendor="apple"
8f:91:34 vendor="dell"
93:ab:c6 vendor="sun"
```

So all what's left is to add `uniq -c` to do the counting:

```
$ join <(sort text.txt) <(sort vendor.xml) | uniq -c
      2 00:10:f6 vendor="micro"
      1 03:48:03 vendor="apple"
      1 8f:91:34 vendor="dell"
      1 93:ab:c6 vendor="sun"
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's an awk answer:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {count[$0]++; next} $1 in count {print count[$1],$0}' text.txt vendor.xml | sort -nr
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first two commands are not doing anything. You are catting the two files and passing them to grep which is ignoring it since you have given it a file to search in. You only needed

```
grep -Ff text.txt vendor.xml | sort -u | uniq -c
```

That doesn't work the way you expected because `grep` is smarter than that. When you give it a list of patterns to look for, it will ignore duplicates. This means that it only prints one line for the two `00:10:f6` in `text.txt`:

```
$ grep -Ff text.txt vendor.xml 
03:48:03 vendor="apple"
00:10:f6 vendor="micro"
8f:91:34 vendor="dell"
93:ab:c6 vendor="sun"
```

As for what you were trying to do, others have already given you very good suggestions, but here's a perl one:

```
$ perl -lane '$#F>0 ? $k{$F[0]} && print "$k{$F[0]} $_" : $k{$_}++;' text.txt vendor.xml 
1 03:48:03 vendor="apple"
2 00:10:f6 vendor="micro"
1 8f:91:34 vendor="dell"
1 93:ab:c6 vendor="sun"
```